# Request for explanation in easy words

Tags: claims, us8463238

In reference to the patent: [US8463238](https://www.google.com/patents/US8463238)

What does this patent claim? Could someone please explain the scope of this patent in plain English?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original question "scope of this  patent" is narrowed down to whether  "already connected wifi connection can be shared or not" comes in the scope of claims , in the comment posted as response to Eric's comment (dated Oct 17, 17).

If the question is aimed at accessing wi-fi network through the device of the invention, the answer in brief is  "YES".

Independent cliam 1 citation, "access point for a wireless network", encompasses all wireless networks of present and even of future and arguably includes wi-fi too. Dependent claim 8 (besides claim 4 citing cellular network) citing, "the wireless network is from a group of wireless networks consisting of wireless local  area network (WLAN), ..." is supported by mention of  802.11 standard in specification and the term Wi-Fi is mentioned in summary of the invention. This nails the issue. Wi-fi refers to IEEE802.11 standard and is trade name for this standard applied in LWAN devices by Wi-Fi Alliances.

But 'already connected wi-fi connection can  be shared or not' is different issue. Say user 'A' is connected to a wi-fi network. 'A' wants to share the network he is connected to with user 'B' through the access point of the invention. To the best of my belief, this issue is not covered by claim scope of the patent in question nor by the specification.

My interpretation of the claims is, besides normal device functions, the mobile device can be 'set up' as base station (access point) for accessing a 'wireless network'. User 'A' can access a wireless network (including wi-fi) through the device of the invention which the device has access to and cannot connect (link) user 'B' to a network which he himself (A) is connected (linked) to.

Comment: Could you please look over this patent number registered with the IPO. 201641036244. The information on the same can be found in the website https://ipindiaservices.gov.in/PublicSearch/PublicationSearch/ApplicationStatus

Comment: @Aniketh Jain. What exactly is your query?

Comment: My query is if this patent claim is in line with the patent US8463238.

Comment: @Aniketh Jain. I don't think so. Device of US8463238 facilitates access to network (claimed) to other devices.  Device of IPO. 201641036244 comprises communication device (claim 1) to access a host computer (claim 2(v)) through appropriate network(not construed as claim). To me they are not related in any manner claim wise. To put in better perspective device of 201641036244 can use device of US8463238 as means to communicate with its host computer.

Comment: Thank you so much for your input. Appreciate your time and effort for this.

Answer (score 0):

They claim that they can make a cellphone into an internet service provider of sorts for a number of chosen users.  In other words, several other users can get the internet through one mobile device without using their own plans.  I believe Apple has it now.

Comment: how is the one mobile device getting the internet?

Comment: Through their cellular provider from cell towers or a satellite service.

Comment: Essentially this what people call a mobile hot spot. Your computer connects by WiFi with your phone and the phone provides the connection to the internet through the cellular signal. I've done it and it works great.

Comment: From what I could tell, the claims don't say how or even that the first device is getting internet service. It could be an internal wireless network, perhaps even a wireless network that only offers access to the main phone (server).

Comment: @3dalliance. The assignee of this invention is 'Apple'.

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting my comment to 3dalliance's answer as an answer since it might be a bit simpler to understand.

Essentially this what people call a mobile hot spot. Your computer connects by WiFi with your phone and the phone provides the connection to the internet through the cellular signal. I've done it with my iPhone and it works great assuming your cellular connection is good.

Comment: So it does not speak of sharing the connection if the provider is another wifi and not the cellular connection.

Comment: @AnikethJain it's been a few months so I'd have to review the patent. On my iPhone, you turn the mobile hotspot on and it looks like any other SSID. There would be no point to connecting with your phone which is connected to wifi.

Comment: Hey Eric. thanks for replying. Sorry for the delayed response. What I have in mind is if the patent is referring to the connection specifically to be a cellular connection only. I want to check if the statement "already connected wifi connection can be shared or not" comes in the scope of the patent.

Answer (score 0):

Tethering.

It basically claims a cell phone that can do certain things which, of course, pretty much all cell phones can do -- particularly, things like tethering. Claim one is limited in that the phone can stop devices after the first one from tethering, and limit the number of devices that can tether based on time or place. Most of the claims after it look very obvious to me, but maybe some of them aren't. If you want more specific an analysis than that in plain English, hire an attorney.